# How to change the font size gradually in a UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, uilabel

is there a way to change the font size gradually in a UILabel? I tried it with:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"foo" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
uiLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:144];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The problem is that the change of the font size happens instantly.

Comment: What was your starting size? Maybe try changing with smaller increments?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the size. I tried a lot sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, look at this (it is a sample project for the iPhone): [link text](http://drp.ly/Gl9cb)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the `font` property is animateable.

Comment: You could try modifying the `layer` property of the UILabel to perform your animation. That's just a guess, though. Good luck!